# Dataweave Escape Double Quote and , while reading a json and writing to csv

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

am getting json and trying to bulk load to salesforce as a csv . But am getting errors when i do that .

Any idea how to escape the characters?

Input:

```
[
  {
    
    "Name": ".054\" X 6' ,  Guide \\ Wire2",

   
  }
]
```

dw:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv escape="",quote=""
---
payload
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following this [Bulk API v2 Salesforce Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-csv), I think the Dataweave writer configuration you need is the following one:

```
output application/csv quote="\"",quoteValues=true,escape="\""
```